# Numba-compatible implementation of np.tile?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm working on some code for dehazing images, [based on this paper](http://kaiminghe.com/publications/cvpr09.pdf), and I started with an abandoned [Py2.7 implementation](https://github.com/cssartori/image-dehazing). Since then, particularly with Numba, I've made some real performance improvements (important since I'll have to run this on 8K images).

I'm pretty convinced my last significant performance bottleneck is in performing the [box filter step](https://github.com/tigerhawkvok/image-dehazing/blob/08dc699c9128af7e73dbaef1c78a1a840d142ddb/src/Refine.py#L133-L166) (I've already shaved off almost a minute per image, but this last slow step is ~30s/image), and I'm close to getting it to run as `nopython` in Numba:

```py
@njit # Row dependencies means can't be parallel
def yCumSum(a):
    """
    Numba based computation of y-direction
    cumulative sum. Can't be parallel!
    """
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    out[0, :] = a[0, :]
    for i in prange(1, a.shape[0]):
        out[i, :] = a[i, :] + out[i - 1, :]
    return out

@njit(parallel= True)
def xCumSum(a):
    """
    Numba-based parallel computation
    of X-direction cumulative sum
    """
    out = np.empty_like(a)
    for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
        out[i, :] = np.cumsum(a[i, :])
    return out

@jit
def _boxFilter(m, r, gpu= hasGPU):
    if gpu:
        m = cp.asnumpy(m)
    out = __boxfilter__(m, r)
    if gpu:
        return cp.asarray(out)
    return out

@jit(fastmath= True)
def __boxfilter__(m, r):
    """
    Fast box filtering implementation, O(1) time.
    Parameters
    ----------
    m:  a 2-D matrix data normalized to [0.0, 1.0]
    r:  radius of the window considered
    Return
    -----------
    The filtered matrix m'.
    """
    #H: height, W: width
    H, W = m.shape
    #the output matrix m'
    mp = np.empty(m.shape)

    #cumulative sum over y axis
    ySum = yCumSum(m) #np.cumsum(m, axis=0)
    #copy the accumulated values of the windows in y
    mp[0:r+1,: ] = ySum[r:(2*r)+1,: ]
    #differences in y axis
    mp[r+1:H-r,: ] = ySum[(2*r)+1:,: ] - ySum[ :H-(2*r)-1,: ]
    mp[(-r):,: ] = np.tile(ySum[-1,: ], (r, 1)) - ySum[H-(2*r)-1:H-r-1,: ]

    #cumulative sum over x axis
    xSum = xCumSum(mp) #np.cumsum(mp, axis=1)
    #copy the accumulated values of the windows in x
    mp[:, 0:r+1] = xSum[:, r:(2*r)+1]
    #difference over x axis
    mp[:, r+1:W-r] = xSum[:, (2*r)+1: ] - xSum[:, :W-(2*r)-1]
    mp[:, -r: ] = np.tile(xSum[:, -1][:, None], (1, r)) - xSum[:, W-(2*r)-1:W-r-1]
    return mp
```

There's plenty to do around the edges, but if I can get the tile operation as a nopython call, I can nopython the whole boxfilter step and get a big performance boost. I'm not super inclined to do something really really specific as I'd love to reuse this code elsewhere, but I wouldn't particularly object to it being limited to a 2D scope. For whatever reason I'm just staring at this and not really sure where to start.

Comment: have you looked at the `tile` code.?  It uses `np.repeat` which is compiled

Comment: You might be able to avoid `tile` by breaking the array assignment into pieces.  Off hand it looks like you are using `tile` to expand one `Sum` slice to work with another, and then assign it to `mp`.  I've haven't taken the time to work out the details.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize `tile` was using `repeat` under the hood; I'll take a look in a few hours

Comment: You don't need tile at all. Just write it loops without any vectorized command. This would also lead to a speed-up of your code. (All vectorized commands except BLAS calls are transformed to (multiple) loops. Numba tries to simplify this, but a human programmer is usually far better in doing such loop joining.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`np.tile` is a [bit too complicated](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L1155-L1244) to reimplement in full, but unless I'm misreading it looks like you only need to take a vector and then repeat it along a different axis `r` times.

A Numba-compatible way to do this is to write

```
y = x.repeat(r).reshape((-1, r))
```

Then `x` will be repeated `r` times along the second dimension, so that `y[i, j] == x[i]`.

Example:

```
In [2]: x = np.arange(5)                                                                                                

In [3]: x.repeat(3).reshape((-1, 3))                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

If you want `x` to be repeated along the first dimension instead, just take the transpose `y.T`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Had to do some [copy-slice-reshape fixes](https://github.com/tigerhawkvok/image-dehazing/blob/7758d7dddb5c61a0cb6c9f4e832bb321e56fb946/src/Refine.py#L158-L170) but it did work out!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this answer. If the exact function of np.tile is needed for a 1D array, just do: np.repeat([1,2,3,4], 3).reshape(-1, 3).T.flatten() >>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])